# How can I get http://host from headers() of nextjs (next/headers)

Tags: next.js, http-headers

I have made a small project to connect GraphQL with Apollo in Nextjs 13

In server side, I have tried to connect with graphQL server which I have implemented in "/api/graphql".

My problem is the link url, I have tried get the url by **next/headers** like below

```js
import { HttpLink } from "@apollo/client";
import { headers } from "next/headers";
import {
  NextSSRInMemoryCache,
  NextSSRApolloClient,
} from "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/ssr";
import { registerApolloClient } from "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/rsc";

export const { getClient } = registerApolloClient(() => {
  const headersList = headers();
  return new NextSSRApolloClient({
    cache: new NextSSRInMemoryCache(),
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: `${headersList.get("host")}/api/graphql`,
    }),
  });
});
```

```
${headersList.get("host")}/api/graphql
```

But it only show "localhost:3000/api/graphql", Do you have any solution for me to display "http://localhost:3000/api/graphql" because maybe it change to "https" when I deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Try `X-Forwarded-Host` header instead of the `host` header and it may work.

See the [X-Forwarded-Host](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Host) documentation

Comment: Thank you for the recommend, but it still show "localhost:3000/api/graphql" :(